# How do I know which users are accessing my API hosted in Azure AD OAuth 2.0 so they only access their private data?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, access-token, restful-authentication, azure-active-directory

I have developed a Web API, hosted in Azure, with OAuth 2.0 Authorization grant thru Azure AD. I have the token system working, I am able to request an authorization code, and use that to request access/refresh token, and then request data from the API in general.

The next thing I am struggling with is how do I allow user A to access Database A data and user B to access Database B data. We have different databases and each user has their own private data. Both user A and B are using the same native "client" desktop application. So here is my thought process:

We could make user A its own "application" in Azure AD, and user B its own "application" in Azure AD. They would have different access tokens then. But how do I know in my Web API that user A is calling my API, or user B is calling my API if Azure AD is the one doing the authorization? is there a way to extract which particular user is calling the API from which token is used or something, so I can pull data for only that user? All I have currently is the [Authorize] at the top of the ApiController for the different REST calls and then setting up the application in Azure AD, but that is just general authorization access to the API, not specific permission/authenticated access to private user data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using OWIN/Katana with JWT support for authorization.  If so, then you should find that if you get the ClaimsPrincipal.Current property there will be a ClaimsPrincipal object that represents the user that was authenticated.  It will contain a set of claims that are returned from AzureAD.  You can use those claims to retrieve an identifier for the user and map that to their associated database.

Take a look at the sample here:

https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebAPI-OnBehalfOf-DotNet

In particular this file:

https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebAPI-OnBehalfOf-DotNet/blob/master/TodoListService/Controllers/TodoListController.cs

line 80:

`// A user's To Do list is keyed off of the NameIdentifier claim, which contains an immutable, unique identifier for the user.
    Claim subject = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);`

After this code the `subject.Value` property will contain an identifier for the authenticated user.

This link contains some documentation on the set of claims that Azure AD will return:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151790.aspx

Search for "Azure AD issues a fixed set of claims for the authenticated users."

Comment: ...how do I know which user is which unique name identifier. is there a list of them?